# 2 useState's inside a useEffect one works , other does not even though they are almost the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I've got this `useEffect` function set up to run just once when the page renders.

Inside it I am using two `useState` functions : `setPageLenght` and `setPages`

- They are defined as follows

```
const [pages,setPages] = useState([])
const [pageLenght,setPageLenght] = useState(0)
```

- Both of them are called here

```
useEffect(() => fetchData(props.Token).then(response => {
    let result = Math.round(response[0] / 20)
    setPageLenght(prev => result); //Does not change the state remains at 0
        
    for (let i=0;i < result;i++) {
        let page = <span>response[i]</span>;
        setPages(prev => [...prev,page])
    }
}),[])
```

Basically it calls a function that fetches data and then sets the data accordingly

The latter one `setPages` works fine, but for some reason the first one does not.

**What is going on here?**

Comment: try `console.log(response[0])` to see the value if its greater than 10?

Comment: response[0] is 80 does that matter?

Comment: How are these two state updates almost the same, they do completely different things? How are you verifying the first state update isn't working?

Comment: `console.log(pageLength)` is always stuck at the initial state 0, both the useState functions fetch data from the same source one is an array of  JSX elements representing the extracted data, the other is an integer of one of those extracted values

Comment: I don't see any console logging in the snippet. Please update your question to include all relevant code you have an issue with. If you are trying to log `pageLenght` *right* after updating it, state is `const` and updates are batched and processed *between* render cycles.